# How to access SQlite returned data globally in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, object, getter-setter

```
public class MainObj {
    private static final MainObj instance = new MainObj();

    public static MainObj getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static class User {
        public int account_id;
        public String user_id;
        public String sip_id;
        public String username;
        public String fullname;
        public boolean active;
        public boolean status;

        public int getAccount_id() {
            return account_id;
        }
        public void setAccount_id(int account_id) {
            Log.e("myphone", account_id+"");
            this.account_id = account_id;
        }
        public String getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }
        public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
        }
        public String getSip_id() {
            return sip_id;
        }
        public void setSip_id(String sip_id) {
            this.sip_id = sip_id;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getFullname() {
            return fullname;
        }
        public void setFullname(String fullname) {
            this.fullname = fullname;
        }
        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }
        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }
        public boolean isStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setStatus(boolean status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
    }
}
```

I write sip application on Android. I have some kind of information about user logged in. I want to make something like that.

1. User object with user settings (stored in SQlite)
2. Access user data from SQlite data and store in Object
3. Use user data directly from Object like (in UI activity, fragment ...):

```
User user = new User();
Log.i("TAG", user.sip_id);
```

**or**

```
Log.i("TAG", user.getSip_id());
```

```
// get user data from table
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM user";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        MainObj.User user = new MainObj.User();
        user.setSip_id(cursor.getString(1));
        user.setAccount_id(cursor.getString(2));
        .... and so on
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user
    return user;
}
```

I don't know how to google correctly, because i've searched about 3 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the code like this an you will be able to access the data everywhere.

```
import android.util.Log;

public class User {
    private static final User instance = new User();

    public static User getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private User() {
        super();
    }

    private int account_id;
    private String user_id;
    private String sip_id;
    private String username;
    private String fullname;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean status;

    public int getAccount_id() {
        return account_id;
    }

    public void setAccount_id(int account_id) {
        Log.e("myphone", account_id + "");
        this.account_id = account_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getSip_id() {
        return sip_id;
    }

    public void setSip_id(String sip_id) {
        this.sip_id = sip_id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

You can set data to the user obj by accessing the instance like this

```
//get user data from table
public void getUserDetails() {
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM user";

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();

 if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
     //If you want you can hold the reference in a User obj = User.getInstance(); just to write less code
     User.getInstance().setSip_id(cursor.getString(1));
     User.getInstance().setAccount_id(cursor.getString(2));
     .... and so on
 }

 cursor.close();
 db.close();
}
```

If you need the data somewhere after you get the data, just do this for example:

```
mEditText.setText(User.getInstance().getUsername());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your **getUserDetails** method.

First, you create a *HashMap* variable called **user**... and, in the *if* block, you created a *MainObj.User* variable called **user** too.

So... what about the collision? In Java, variable scope is block. So, the user created in *if* block is automatically removed when the if block finish, and the return value is the empty *HashMap*.

You can change that method for something like this:

```
// get user data from table
public MainObj.User getUserDetails() {
    MainObj.User user = null;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM user";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user = new MainObj.User();
        user.setSip_id(cursor.getString(1));
        user.setAccount_id(cursor.getString(2));
        .... and so on
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user or null if not data
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list of user details. And if you need to access it from anywhere in your app, put this list in Application class. It maintains a global application state. You can extend your Application class and use that class anywhere in your app by invoking ChildApplication app = (ChildApplication)context.getApplicationContext();

```
public List<MainObj.User> getUSerDetails(){

        List<MainObj.User> userDetails = new ArrayList<MainObj.User>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM user";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
              MainObj.User user = new MainObj.User();
              user.setSip_id(cursor.getString(1));
              user.setAccount_id(cursor.getString(2));
               .... and so on
              userDetails.add(user);
}

cursor.close();
db.close();

return userDetails;
}
```